# Como retornar a URL do redirect com js?

Tags: javascript, funções, redirect

Tenho uma URL que redireciona para outra URL onde está o `Location` com a URL final, quero retornar em um `var urlfinal` apenas a URL final que está neste `Location`, e não a URL que está direcionando para lá.

Abaixo está o mais perto que cheguei de conseguir isso, porem não consigo fazer um `return urlfinal` por exemplo.

Código:

```
function RetornaUrlFinal(url){
const url = redirect;
let bloburl = void 0;
let img = new Image;
const getResourceName = fetch(url)
    .then(response => Promise.all([response.url, response.blob()]))
    .then(([resource, blob]) => {
      bloburl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      img.src = bloburl;
      document.body.appendChild(img);
      return resource
    });
    getResourceName.then(res => console.log(res)).catch(err => console.log(err))
    //return urlfinal;
}
```

Código, segunda tentativa falha:

```
function testRedirect(url) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var urlredirect;
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
    if (xhr.status == 200 && xhr.readyState == 4) {
      if (url != xhr.responseURL) {
        //alert("redirect detected to: " + xhr.responseURL)
        return xhr.responseURL;
        console.log("URL:" + xhr.responseURL);
      } else {
        console.log("Erro na URL:" + xhr.responseURL);
      }
    }
  }
  xhr.open("GET", url, true);
  xhr.send();
}
```

Existe alguma maneira de conseguir isso em javascript? Não necessariamente tem de ser com esse código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fala ae Florida,
Você precisa dar um return em getResourceName e tratar essa function como promisse.

**Exemplo:**

```
function redirecionarComNovaUrl(){
    RetornaUrlFinal(url)
    .then(res => { window.location = res.url; })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}

function RetornaUrlFinal(url){
const url = redirect;
let bloburl = void 0;
let img = new Image;
const getResourceName = fetch(url)
    .then(response => Promise.all([response.url, response.blob()]))
    .then(([resource, blob]) => {
      bloburl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      img.src = bloburl;
      document.body.appendChild(img);
      return resource
    });
    return getResourceName;
}
```